# Can someone please explain why it is the *smallest* subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am reading *field theory* and having trouble with:

As *Fraleigh* writes:

Let $E$ be an extension of $F$ .Define $\phi_\alpha:F[x]\to E;\phi_\alpha(a)=a;a\in F,\phi_\alpha(x)=\alpha$ .
Suppose that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$. Let $irr(\alpha,F)$  is the monic irreducible polynomial of which $\alpha $ is a root.
Then $F[x]/<irr(\alpha,F)>$ is  a field and is isomorphic to subfield $\phi_\alpha [F[x]]$ of $E$.

the  subfield $\phi_\alpha [F[x]]$ of $E$ is the **smallest subfield** of $E$ containing $F$ and $\alpha $.

Can someone please explain why it is the *smallest* subfield ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, $K=F[x]/(irr(\alpha,F))$ is isomorphic to $K'=\phi_{\alpha}(F[x])$ by the first isomorphism theorem. Since $irr(\alpha,F)$ is irreducible, $K$ is a field, and so is $K'$.

Let $L$ a subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and $\alpha$. Since $L$ is a field, it is a ring (in particular it is stable under addition and multiplication), and thus all polynomial combinations like $a_n \alpha^n + \cdots + a_1 \alpha + a_0$ (with $a_i \in F$) must belong to $L$. Therefore $K'$ is contained in $L$.

This means that $K'$ is the smallest subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and $\alpha$, since every other such subfield contains $K'$.